# How do I show the name who has the most dates? like max(count(max(date)))

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max, inner-join

I thought something like this:

```
SELECT l.vorname
     , l.nachname 
  FROM leser l 
  JOIN ausleihe a 
    ON l.LeserNr = a.LeserNr 
 WHERE MAX(COUNT(a.gemahnt)) = 
    (SELECT = COUNT(gemahnt) AS Anzahl 
       FROM ausleihe 
     WHERE Anzahl = (SELECT MAX(Anzahl)));
```

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Use enough words & sentences to say what you mean. Put your question in the post body. What does that code have to do with "dates"? Also: This is (obviously) a faq. Please google many clear phrasings of a question. [ask] When you do ask re code give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
l.Vorname, l.Nachname, COUNT(a.gemahnt) AS Anzahl
    FROM
leser l
    JOIN
ausleihe a ON l.LeserNr = a.LeserNr
   WHERE
a.gemahnt IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.LeserNr
HAVING Anzahl = (SELECT 
    COUNT(gemahnt)
FROM
    ausleihe
WHERE
    gemahnt IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LeserNr
ORDER BY COUNT(gemahnt) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

:D